# Analysis of ANOVA Table to Determine Polynomial Degree

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, anova, econometrics

Using time-series data, I'm trying to determine the optimal polynomial degree to use for my regression. To do this, I chose to run an ANOVA test on 5 models, the first model's degree is equal to 1 and each successive model's degree increases by 1. So, model 3's degree is equal to 3 and model 5's degree is equal to 5.

I've included the results from my model below:
[image: ANOVA Table]

Based on this table, I am interpreting the table as model 2, which has a polynomial degree equal to 2, is the optimal model to use for my analysis. Where I'm getting confused is, do I stop considering all higher order polynomial degrees once the probability is not significant? In this instance that would be model 3. Model's 4 and 5 are indicating that the additional degrees are significant but should I consider them as well?

Comment: I would not use ANOVA or p values to do this. I would use my eyes.  Or, if you wish, use a spline.

Comment: Can you give me a little more context on why not to use ANOVA? I was also thinking of using AIC to determine the degree.

Comment: Sorry, I get why ANOVA shouldn't be used, because the independence assumption is violated.

Comment: No, I wouldn't use it because p values and tests aren't useful in this context.  The question is not whether the difference in fit between a cubic, quadratic, or linear fit (or any other) is statistically significant, but whether it is practically important.   How far from straight is the fit?